# TypeError: this.name is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the below code I always get an error "TypeError: this.verifyUrl is not a function at Server.ImageServer.handleRequest" even though the function is defined above.

Any hint welcome.

The same applies if i write the sample in pure JavaScript.

```
"use strict";

import Http = require('http');
import Url = require('url');

export class ImageServer {

    port: number;
    server: Http.Server;

    constructor(port: number) {
        this.port = port || 1337;
    }

    run() {
        this.server = Http.createServer(this.handleRequest);
        this.server.listen(this.port);
    }

    verifyUrl(urlitems: Url.Url) {
        return true;
    }

    handleRequest(req: Http.IncomingMessage, res: Http.ServerResponse) {
        console.log('request: ', req.url);
        var urlitems = Url.parse(req.url, true);
        var pathitems = urlitems.path.split('/').slice(1);

        console.log('url: ', urlitems);
        console.log('path: ', pathitems);

        if (!this.verifyUrl(urlitems)) {
            this.sendNotFound(res);
            return;
        }

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.end('Hello World\n');
    }

    sendNotFound(res: Http.ServerResponse) {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end();
        return undefined;
    }

}
```

Comment: On what line are you getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
"use strict";

import Http = require('http');
import Url = require('url');

export class ImageServer {

    port: number;
    server: Http.Server;

    constructor(port: number) {
        this.port = port || 1337;
    }

    run() {
        this.server = Http.createServer(this.handleRequest);
        this.server.listen(this.port);
    }

    verifyUrl(urlitems: Url.Url) {
        return true;
    }

    handleRequest = (req: Http.IncomingMessage, res: Http.ServerResponse) => {
        console.log('request: ', req.url);
        var urlitems = Url.parse(req.url, true);
        var pathitems = urlitems.path.split('/').slice(1);

        console.log('url: ', urlitems);
        console.log('path: ', pathitems);

        if (!this.verifyUrl(urlitems)) {
            this.sendNotFound(res);
            return;
        }

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.end('Hello World\n');
    }

    sendNotFound(res: Http.ServerResponse) {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end();
        return undefined;
    }

}
```

I suppose you call `handleRequest` as a callback from a module (probably `expressjs`?), so `this` is not binded to the class scope but to the module's scope. Using arrow functions, `this` will be automatically assigned to the class scope and so you can access to your class functions/properties

Here's your problem explained with examples

```
class Hi {
   hello: string = "Hello world!";

   haha(req: Http.IncomingMessage, res: Http.ServerResponse) {
      console.log(this.hello) // print undefined or error
   }
}

var hi = new Hi();

app.get("/foo", hi.haha);
```

With this code, you can't access to the class properties because `this` is assigned to express.

You can fix it as said above with arrow functions. Here's a working example:

```
class Hi {
   hello: string = "Hello world!";

   haha = (req: Http.IncomingMessage, res: Http.ServerResponse) => {
      console.log(this.hello) // print Hello world!
   }
}

var hi = new Hi();

app.get("/foo", hi.haha);
```

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance it looks like a scope issue since at the time of invokation `this` refers to the scope of Http.createServer(). A quick fix would be to bind to the actual object scope imo.